# jquery chart API and plugins

Tags: api, jquery-plugins, charts

What is **chart API**,
what is **chart plugin**,
how many type of chat API,
specially *jQuery chart API* and *jQuery chart plugin*???

Comment: You seem to have done little or no reading before asking this question. It is very broad and hard to answer without writing an essay...

 There is plenty of information available on plugins in general (Starting with https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/) and there are several different chart plugins and chart APIs. 

Try to do a bit of reading to understand the subject, then start implementing your solution and come back if you have more specific questions.

Comment: Chart API is what exactly draw the graphics on the screen based on the data (also populate the data,)  a chart plugin uses it to customise the way the chart is drawn. where google charts is the API,   try this jQuery Plugin for googlechart using google vizualization data, https://github.com/cosmoarunn/gapiExt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart API is a tool that lets people easily create a chart from some data and embed it in a web page.

Currently, line, bar, pie, and radar charts, as well as Venn diagrams, scatter plots, sparklines, maps, google-o-meters, and QR codes are supported by multiple API for example Google Chart API.You pass your data to Google server and it Generate Chart on based of Passed data.

Example Chart using Google api

[image: Example Google chart]

Chart Plugin do similar jobs but you do not need to pass data to another server.

example http://www.chartjs.org/

There are many types of Chart Api and plugins are available.Some are paid and some are free to use.

Few are

[highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

[chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org)

[dimplejs](http://dimplejs.org/)

Comment: **Thank you** and i got some idea on your point, if suppose i will get some chart code from my colleagues, how can i identify the API and PLUGIN used in... is any standards for that???

Comment: Is my understanding is right, **This is APi '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>' we are passing data to server and chart is displayed...** and **this is plugin '<script type="text/javascript" src=C:\Downloads\Highcharts-4.1.7\js\highcharts.js' here we dont send data to server, instead of sending data to highcharts.js**